# HTML displayed using Data URI can't access relative paths

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri, data-uri-scheme

I have an HTML string with me like this:

```
var str = "<html><head><link href='abc.css'/><script src='js/a.js'></script><title>hello</title></head><body><div><img src='images/abcd.png'></div></body></html>";
```

Now, I need to show this HTML in an iframe, so what I do is set the iframe src as follows:

```
document.getElementById('frameID').setAttribute('src', "data:text/html, " + str);
```

Now, the problem is that the html above requires some resources using relative paths, which is not possible to be accessed directly.

Though I do have all the resources required by the HTML string/file stored in Indexed DB as key value pairs, having key as the path and the value as the data of the file.

I tried doing this by setting an `onload` event on my iframe and then in the handler I try to access the `contentWindow` of the iframe but this has some security issues (since the origins are not the same). By getting the contentWindow I could have manipulated the img and the script tags.

Is there some way to be able to access these resources after setting the `iframe src` as I have shown above?

Please Help, I have been stuck for a long time.

Comment: What do your urls output to, since it's not relative?

Comment: They are not accessed at all - I dont see any network request being sent. By the way a url to a website works just fine

Comment: So `<link href='abc.css'/>` evaluates to `<link href=''/>` in your iFrame?

Comment: I found this blog helpful when doing this awhile back. The last method is the only one that worked for me with the browsers I had to target. see: [Inject Content into a new IFrame](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/)

Comment: @colecmc: It doesn't evaluate to what you are saying, it's just that the resource is not fetched probably because it is in a data uri

Comment: @Roberto: The approach given in the link works, your should probably post the approach as an answer (or should I do it?).

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect -- what [base URL(s)] are the [relative] URL(s) that are featured in the HTML document that you're loading with a `data:` URL, expected to be *relative to*?

A resource loaded by the user agent using `data:` has no "base" for all intents and purposes, and a distinct [*authority*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) (and [*origin*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), incidentally) that does not compare equal to any other.

It's an "ephemeral" document in some sense -- if the document uses URL(s) (an URL is *not* a [file] "path" although it may feature a *pathname*, strictly speaking) that do not feature an authority (i.e. they're so-called "relative" URL(s)), these cannot be used in practice because the user agent won't assume any authority (i.e. the domain part) or some pathname prefix. The analogy would be a street name and house number but without a city and country code to it.

The user agent does *not* use the origin or URL of the document that included the script that loaded the document using relative URL(s), as "base" URL for the document loaded with `data:` scheme. Instead, the origin and base URL for the latter, are assumed to be *distinct* from any other URL using the `data:` scheme, and that is by design -- two resources loaded each using `data:` do *not* share same origin and thus aren't considered to "belong to the same domain". This is motivated in no small part by security reasons -- any script (loaded from a random domain) can create a `data:` URL and load some document which doesn't mean two such documents have anything to do with each other or should belong to the same origin/domain.

There is a solution, although I'd say this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) -- use the [`base` HTML element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-base-element) in the document being loaded with `data:` -- so that the user agent resolves relative URLs using the specified "base" URL.

Answer (score -2):

I would like to comment on the same question, but I cannot comment. I can only tell even you add "./", "~/" or "../" to the paths, such as creating "~/js/a.js", it will not work for a data-uri, because it seems like it cannot reference the base html that you want it to go to.

Research continuing...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).